# Can the low kick check be used against low front or side kick?

Tags: blocking

So let's say that somebody aimed a low side kick or low front kick at your leg. Not all low kicks are roundhouse kicks, right? So can the regular low kick shin-lift block be used against low side kicks and low front kicks?

Comment: You have to adapt the technique a bit but I watched a video just yesterday showing how this is done in karate and shorinji kempo.  I'll try to find it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOQQRpmgJ1g&pageId=101381467465090331999
Is this the kind of thing  you mean?  Front kicks to groin at the begining, side kicks at the end.  2 martial arts styles shown.

Comment: Yeah what I mean is like groin kicks and side kicks to groin or knee or just any low front or side kick

Comment: I'll post this as an answer later today.

Comment: Yes that technique can be used against those two kicks, but how low is "low"? If the low front kick was already aimed at your shin, you can either move the leg or just take it on the shin. If "low" is higher than that then the raised leg/shin becomes an obstacle which should at least partially obstruct the incoming kick.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Assuming that the low front or side kick was aimed at the knee (my experience with people suggesting such a technique, although admittedly in TMA classes without stress testing) in order to damage the joint, lifting that leg not only lifts the vulnerable joint above the attack, but also lets you distribute the force of their attack against the length of your shin, which can now bend at the knee to further blunt the force.

Comment: @SuperHuman233: Is there anything else I can offer to this answer?

Comment: No, and thank you for your answer. Here you go, 350 reputation to you.